# Keycloak Angular Integration Issue For Token API

Tags: angular, keycloak, keycloak-services, keycloak-rest-api, keycloak-connect

I've integrated Keycloak with my Angular application, and I have Client authentication enabled.

However, when I make a request to the 'http://localhost:8080/realms/admin/protocol/openid-connect/token' API, I'm receiving a '401 Unauthorized' error.

What could be causing this issue, and how can I troubleshoot and resolve it?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.